# Can't exec "gsl-config": No such file or directory at Build.pl

Tags: windows, perl, gsl

I used strawberry perl in windows 7. I need to install Math-GSL-0.36.

using command:

```
perl Build.PL
```

But the command give error:

> Checking for GSL using gsl-config
>   Can't exec "gsl-config": No such file or directory at Build.pl line 305.
>
> ---
>
> *** Can't find GSL with gsl-config.
>
> *** Trying with PkgConfig.
>
> PkgConfig is currently needed to find GSL for the compilation of this module.

How to solve this problem? please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `gsl-config` installed, the README.md states that you need to have a proper GSL install before building the module. gsl-config can be found in the following package on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

Comment: Platform is windows not linux/debian

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul Regardless, if you want to use a module, install the packages required.

Comment: I know that, i need to install it. I need to know what will be the process to install it in windows.

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm first hit on google, you should search first

Comment: I installed gsl from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/gsl.php and also added **GnuWin32\bin** to path variable. 
But, I still get this error:
'gsl-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html and download Strawberry Perl **PDL edition**. It comes with bundled gsl binaries (and also with gsl-config).

Other option is to download gsl binaries from http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/32_libs/gcc49-2015Q2/ (v1.16) or http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/32_libs/gcc49-2016Q2/ (v2.1) and simply unpack them into your existing strawberry folder.